# Best way to create separate users table for different organisations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

We have a requirement where different users from different organisations would be using our site (getting built with Laravel). For legal reasons, we are considering keeping each organisations data in separate user's table.

My approach to this is to override the table property in App\User.php. This property get's initialized in constructor using session['company'] as shown below:

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

    protected $table = 'my_testing_table';

    public function __construct() {
        $table = session['company'] . 'users';
    }

    ...
}


class LoginController extends Controller {
    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
        session['company'] = "SomeCompany";
    }
}
```

Modified extra fields in register.blade.php, User.php, etc. Which method or property should be overriden for User Registration (App\RegisterController.php)? Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: This is purely from programming standpoint, I don't know the legalities of your project (anything really). But if at all possible I would strongly consider keeping users in the same table. It will be much less duplicated code and much easier maintanance (unless each user really will require all types of different data). That beign said, even if you really need to have separate tables, I definitely wouldn't fetch the table with constructor. It's hacky and probably breaks more things than it fixes. [setTable()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setTable).

Comment: But if at all possible, try to make a separate model for each organisation. This should be much less messy and more readable. Then you can add those models to [config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L67) for the `Auth` functionality to work.

Comment: Thanks for replying devk. Absolutely, the best approach would be a single users table. But legal decisions are planned by higher ups in the organisation. :) I am just considering alternatives, feasibility and costs.